# get the value of label in asp:repeater in jquery modal popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to get the value of of a label in asp:reader in a jquery popup. I have tested this tutorial [ASP.NET Repeater with jQuery Dialog Popup](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1034741/ASP-NET-Repeater-with-jQuery-Dialog-Popup-Reading) and it works fine. However when I try to use the same concept in my script no data is shown. I have viewed the code behind and there are values. Here is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnclickedit").click(function () {
            var currentRow = $(this).parents("tr");
            var MBBody = currentRow.find("span[id*='messageBody']").text();
            $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_bmessageedit").text(MBBody);
            $("#divpopupedit").dialog({
                width: 600,
                height: 580,
                title: "Edit a Message",
                modal: true,
            });
        });
    })
</script>

<div id="divpopupedit" style="display: none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="BodyMessage">Reply:</label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="bmessageedit" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="MessageBoardIDEdit" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="messageBox">
            <table id="messageDetails">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="title" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("MessageTitle") %>' runat="server" />
                <span class="subtitle">Posted By: <%# Eval("EmployeeName") %> | <%# Eval("DateTimePosted") %> </span><span id="messageED" class="messageActions" runat="server">
                    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="btnclickedit">Edit</button>
                    |
                    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="btnclickdelete">Delete</button>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="messageBody" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="MBCategoryID" Value='<%# Eval("MBCategoryID") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="PostedBy" Value='<%# Eval("PostedBy") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="MessageBoardID" Value='<%# Eval("MessageBoardID") %>' runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
            </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**UPDATE**
When I hard code a value the data is displayed. So the issue is the JQuery script does not read the messageBody label value in the repeater.

```
var currentRow = $(this).parents("tr");
var MBBody = "15";
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_bmessageedit").text(MBBody);
```

Comment: have you tried setting breakpoints? also where are you parsing the result from the database and `$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_MessageID").val();` what is this doing? what textbox are you wanting to assign to this value `string MessageID ` what is this being used for? I think you should return the data async first then display a modal popup and take out the async:false part, you say you can't show data, and there is data..but only thing I see you returning is "True" from the web method have you thought about returning a datatable?

Comment: @MethodMan I created a datatable as suggested but I still do not get any data returned to  me in the two textboxes. When I do an alert within the success function, I get an response with a value but it does not show in the textboxes.

Comment: what is the textbox ID or name that you are trying to populate ?

Comment: you need to separate the values being assigned for Message and MessageID you still are not showing correctly how to assign data from the  postback

Comment: @MethodMan I am trying to populate two textboxes MessageID and Message. How do I separate the values?

Comment: Ideally, it is best to return a JSON object instead of a single string, however, to keep it simple, you can use some unique string to separate your MessageID and Message like return MessageID + "$$$" + Message. Then in your success callback, split it using "$$$" then assign the values to respective fields.

Comment: In your 'return', you are concatenating the MessageID and the Message together, without anything to separate them to make it easier for later identifying the two strings.

Comment: After further testing I narrowed down the actual error. So I  edited the question and question title to before reflect what is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by using the `class`, rather that `id` to identify the button that was clicked in a Repeater. (Note that in a Repeater there are multiple instances of `id="btnclickedit"`, so that would not work anyway.

Then in the javascript you are looking for the `messageBody` in the same `tr`, but it is in the next.

So change the button to this, with a unique class name `btnclickedit` added

```
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all btnclickedit" id="btnclickedit">Edit</button>
```

Then we do the same with the `Label` CssClass

```
<asp:Label CssClass="messageBody" ID="messageBody" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>' runat="server" />
```

Now the modify the script to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnclickedit').click(function () {
            var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
            var MBBody = currentRow.next('tr').find('.messageBody').text();

            ....
        });
    });
</script>
```

On a side note, while this works

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_bmessageedit").text(MBBody);
```

it would be better to use the ClientID, especially since you are working with a Master Page.

```
$("#<%= bmessageedit.ClientID %>").text(MBBody);
```

Or if you do not need the ASP functionality, make it a "normal" div.